# drawRect doesn't draws the right shape

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a `UIView` subclass called `TestView` with an overriding of `DrawRect` like that:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TestView: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let rectangle5Color = UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 1.000, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1.000)
        let rectangle5StrokeColor = UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 1.000, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1.000)

        let rectangle5Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
        rectangle5Path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 758, y: 1467))
        rectangle5Path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 748, y: 1467))
        rectangle5Path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 204, y: 1467))
        rectangle5Path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 204, y: 1205))
        rectangle5Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 266, y: 1205), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 204, y: 1205), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 248.33, y: 1205))
        rectangle5Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 754, y: 1135), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 411.79, y: 1205), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 627.68, y: 1135))
        rectangle5Path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 758, y: 1135))
        rectangle5Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 1232, y: 1205), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 884.32, y: 1135), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 1086.21, y: 1205))
        rectangle5Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 1296, y: 1205), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 1233.67, y: 1205), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 1296, y: 1205))
        rectangle5Path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 1296, y: 1467))
        rectangle5Path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 758, y: 1467))
        rectangle5Path.closePath()
        rectangle5Path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 752.5, y: 1009))
        rectangle5Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 867, y: 1122.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 815.74, y: 1009), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 867, y: 1059.82))
        rectangle5Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 752.5, y: 1236), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 867, y: 1185.18), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 815.74, y: 1236))
        rectangle5Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 638, y: 1122.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 689.26, y: 1236), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 638, y: 1185.18))
        rectangle5Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 752.5, y: 1009), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 638, y: 1059.82), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 689.26, y: 1009))
        rectangle5Path.closePath()
        rectangle5Color.setFill()
        rectangle5Path.fill()
        rectangle5StrokeColor.setStroke()
        rectangle5Path.lineWidth = 5
        rectangle5Path.stroke()
    }
}
```

On my `ViewController` I'm adding this view as a subclass to the view like that:

```
let testView = TestView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 100))
self.view.addSubview(testView)
```

but the only thing it draws it a white circle instead of the shape it should draw.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)`, with a `rect` of 100 x 100. So I'd expect a circle.

If you don't want to draw the circle, initialize the path with `UIBezierPath()` instead.

In terms of why you didn't see anything else, your paths are well outside the 100 x 100 size, so I'm not sure what you expected it to render. You should adjust those coordinates to fall within the size of the `TestView` if you want it to render this path within the view.

Comment: I've already tried `UIBezierPath()` but it doesn't show anything then

Comment: Yeah, well all of your coordinates are much larger than 100 (the max width and height of your view), so again, I'm not sure what you expected it to render. Scale those values to fall within the size of the `TestView`.